# django-rest-framework + swagger ui: ImportError: No module named rest_framework_swagger

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger-ui

I'm trying to add django-rest-swagger ui to my api, but I'm getting `ImportError: No module named rest_framework_swagger` even though I've already done `pip install django-rest-swagger`. I can also see the package installed on my virtualenv through `pip list`. I've tried `python manage.py syncdb` as well but doesn't really do anything. Anyone have some suggestions for me? Thanks.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'rest_framework',
'at_api',
'rest_framework_swagger',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

EDIT: Sys path info

```
>>> import sys
>>> for p in sys.path: print p
...

C:\Users\Andrew\.virtualenvs\adventure_time\lib\site-packages\psycopg2-2.5.3-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\Users\Andrew\.virtualenvs\adventure_time\lib\site-packages\six-1.8.0-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\Andrew\.virtualenvs\adventure_time\lib\site-packages\cssselect-0.9.1-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\Andrew\.virtualenvs\adventure_time\lib\site-packages\pyopenssl-0.14-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\Andrew\.virtualenvs\adventure_time\lib\site-packages\lxml-3.4.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\Users\Andrew\.virtualenvs\adventure_time\lib\site-packages\queuelib-1.2.2-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\Andrew\.virtualenvs\adventure_time\lib\site-packages\w3lib-1.10.0-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\Andrew\.virtualenvs\adventure_time\lib\site-packages\twisted-14.0.2-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\Users\Andrew\.virtualenvs\adventure_time\lib\site-packages\zope.interface-4.1.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\Users\Andrew\.virtualenvs\adventure_time\lib\site-packages\zipline-0.7.0-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\Andrew\.virtualenvs\adventure_time\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.15.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\Users\Andrew\.virtualenvs\adventure_time\lib\site-packages\pywin32-214-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\Users\Andrew\.virtualenvs\adventure_time\lib\site-packages\pyyaml-3.11-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\windows\system32\python27.zip
C:\Users\Andrew\.virtualenvs\adventure_time\DLLs
C:\Users\Andrew\.virtualenvs\adventure_time\lib
C:\Users\Andrew\.virtualenvs\adventure_time\lib\plat-win
C:\Users\Andrew\.virtualenvs\adventure_time\lib\lib-tk
C:\Users\Andrew\.virtualenvs\adventure_time\Scripts
C:\Python27\Lib
C:\Python27\DLLs
C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk
C:\Users\Andrew\.virtualenvs\adventure_time
C:\Users\Andrew\.virtualenvs\adventure_time\lib\site-packages
>>>
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Andrew/Desktop/rocketu/adventure_time/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named rest_framework_swagger

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you give ``sys.path`` content ?

Comment: @KevinBrown Just added it. The django-rest-swagger github repo requirements say Python (2.6.5+, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4),
Django (1.5.5+, 1.6, 1.7),
Django REST framework (2.3.5+), so perhaps this means drf 3.0.0 does not work?

Comment: Latest version of what? My drf is 3.0.0, and my django-rest-swagger is 0.2.2. I think these are already the most up-to-date versions?

Comment: @KevinBrown You mean just type in `python` or `python manage.py shell` then `import rest_framework_bulk`? I did that and I just got back `ImportError: No module named rest_framework_bulk`

Comment: @pyramidface My bad, you need to import `rest_framework_swagger`. My hope is that those tracebacks (if there are any) have some extra details.

Comment: @KevinBrown No errors for both shells :/

Comment: Oh... I figured it out. My project interpreter wasn't actually set up to my virtualenv with django-rest-swagger installed ╰༼=ಠਊಠ=༽╯ Thanks for sticking with me through this @KevinBrown.

Answer (score 9):

Follow these steps to solve:

1- Make sure your Virtual Environment is activated.

2-  install requirements or rest_framework_swagger using pip

```
    pip install django-rest-swagger
```

3- in File-> Settings -> Project Interpreter -> : select virtual environment for your project
4- in toolbar -> Edit configurations...-> python Interpreter : select your project virtual environment

Answer (score 3):

Solved it... It was way more simpler than I had imagined. I just checked to see my project's interpreter, and I noticed that it was not using my virtualenv with django-rest-swagger installed.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. Solved it by installing the rest_framework_swagger using pip

Answer (score 0):

##### FIXED

just run this:

```bash
pip install django-rest-swagger
```